# Empty page occurring between the approval page and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, books, report

Here is my Preamble:

```
\documentclass[openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{grad_proseminar}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[page,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=cyan, }


 \newenvironment{blockquote}{%
\par%
\vskip10pt
\leftskip=2em\rightskip=2em%
\noindent\ignorespaces}{%
\par\vskip10pt}

\title{Alcohol Use in College: Results from a Survey}
\author{Crystal Thompson} 
\advisor{Dr. Anthony Okafor}
\date{Summer 2018}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}

\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
The Proseminar of Crystal Thompson is approved:

\vspace{0.5cm}


\vspace{1.5cm}

 \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrlrr}
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-6}\cmidrule{8-10} Jia Liu, Ph.D., Chair &       &       &       
&       &       &       & Date  &     &  \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{titlepage}
\textbf{\tableofcontents} 
\doublespace 
\abstract
\vskip8pt

\mainmatter
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to delete that empty page that is in between the approval page and the table of contents.

Comment: What does `\usepackage{grad_proseminar}` do? If it is not relevant to the issue, remove it. If it is, please provide it. And there is a `\begin{document}` missing and it seems that some relevant packages are not loaded.

Comment: It a template for my undergraduate proseminar.

Comment: When I take out     \usepackage{grad_proseminar} out of the preamble , there i an error that says that  the command    \advisor is undefined.

Comment: Well there is no link to it, since this temple was provide by my University.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with what you. I see that I tried to take the short cut and tried to include all the important parts about my dilemma and see that I left out a few keep components to the code. Thanks for the nice tips.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question! Sadly, `\advisor` and `\abstract` seem to be defined in ` \usepackage{grad_proseminar}`. And if one comments these lines out, the issue does not arise, i.e. there is no empty page. Any chance your university *wants* that empty page and just wrote the package in such a way that it appears?

Comment: since you're using the `book` class, `\tableofcontents` is likely to start on a right-hand (odd-numbered) page (check for `cleardoublepage` in the definition).  does the approval page start on an odd- or even-numbered page?  (this might be nonsense, since you have specified `oneside` and `openany`, but i don't have access to latex at the moment to check.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\textbf{\tableofcontents}` by `{\bfseries\tableofcontents}`:

```
\documentclass[openany, oneside]{book}
%\usepackage{grad_proseminar}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[page,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=cyan, }


 \newenvironment{blockquote}{%
\par%
\vskip10pt
\leftskip=2em\rightskip=2em%
\noindent\ignorespaces}{%
\par\vskip10pt}

\title{Alcohol Use in College: Results from a Survey}
\author{Crystal Thompson} 
%\advisor{Dr. Anthony Okafor}
\date{Summer 2018}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}

\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
The Proseminar of Crystal Thompson is approved:

\vspace{0.5cm}


\vspace{1.5cm}

 \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrlrr}
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{1-6}\cmidrule{8-10} Jia Liu, Ph.D., Chair &       &       &       
&       &       &       & Date  &     &  \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{titlepage}
{\bfseries\tableofcontents}% <- changed!
\doublespace 
%\abstract
\vskip8pt

\mainmatter
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]